# Byte not written to the memory

Tags: arduino-nano, c++, i2c

In the following code I'm computing crc and setting it as last (11th) byte in the array. The problem is it's sent on I2C just when I print it on the serial terminal.

```
  static constexpr uint8_t CLICK_MESSAGE_SIZE{11};
  ...
  uint8_t buf[CLICK_MESSAGE_SIZE];
  memcpy(buf, msgMouseClick[clickMessageCounter], CLICK_MESSAGE_SIZE);
  buf[10] = dallas_crc8(buf, 10);
  Serial.println(buf[10], HEX); //!!!has to be here, otherwise is CRC in packet wrong!!!
  Wire.write(buf, CLICK_MESSAGE_SIZE);
```

When I'm assig the result of to

```
auto crc = dallas_crc8(buf, 10);
buf[10] = crc;
Serial.println(crc);
```

and Serial.print ing it. Then It's works. But with  `const auto crc = dallas_crc8(buf, 10);` **It does not!**

I have slightly modified Wire library, where I'm passing pointer to the buffer and it's size. With precalculated CRCs on 11th position it's working fine even for hundreds of bytes arrays.

It feels like a black magic, or compiler error. I'm using latest arduino-1.8.10

Any tips or hints?

Comment: The code snippets you show look fine to me. Could you post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing your problem?

Comment: I don't get your problem. What do you mean by "it works" and what by "it does not"? Please provide exactly what you expect and what you get in both cases.

Comment: If the difference is just in serial monitor, maybe that missing HEX is the issue.

Comment: The problem is that without  `Serial.println(buf[10], HEX);` the value of the last byte sent with `Wire.write(buf, CLICK_MESSAGE_SIZE);` is the same like in declaration. Not as calculated and set in `buf[10] = dallas_crc8(buf, 10);`   The `Serial.println(buf[10], HEX);` is cruical for getting the last byte correctly.

Comment: Just to double-check that I understand you correctly: You are saying that without `Serial.println(buf[10], HEX);` the value at `buf[10]` is **not** what you assigned via `buf[10] = dallas_crc8(buf, 10);` when `Wire.write(buf, CLICK_MESSAGE_SIZE);` is executed? Is the value the 11th `uint8_t` from `msgMouseClick[clickMessageCounter]` or any other value? This seems so improbable that I'd like to ask you for a [example]. You might want to minimize it.

Comment: try it with AVR boards package 1.6.21. install it in Boards Manager. it has older version of gcc

Comment: Strangely it helped.

Comment: the new version of gcc is buggy